# GPU Support for Qiskit's SPSA Optimization Algorithm

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, optimization

I am using Qiskit's SPSA optimization algorithm to find the ground state energy of various lattices (fermi-Hubbard model) by running different circuits through it and having the algorithm modify the parameters and angles of the gates. Is there any GPU support for this optimization algorithm to speed up the process? I am running the circuits themselves on NVIDIA GPUs by changing the backend of the Aer-simulator, but I could not find much online about using the GPU for SPSA. If there is no direct GPU support built into the algorithm, does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could use Tensorflow or Pytorch to accomplish this? Many of the examples I have seen so far use the `matmul` command to multiply matrices,  but I am not sure how to use these libraries with the SPSA where an array of parameters (angles for the gates in the circuits) is changing each time and being inputted into the function that is called back on for each iteration.